# Don't want to return the whole object, how to filter out the things that I don't want?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    return res.send({"user": user});
```

the user object returned is like this(see below), but I want to hide the password, confirmationToken and also the __v fields.

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "566786",
        "detail": {
            "lastUpdate": "2015-01-22T22:06:22.951Z",
            "registrationDate": "2015-01-22T02:15:07.379Z",
            "firstName": "Testing",
            "lastName": "Testing",
        },
        "info": {
            "confirmationToken": "3dc917fbfd6f47e",
            "password": "$2a$08$4ugeIPC.5nCMQiyutL11i",
            "email": "testing@abcdefgxxxxxx.com",
        }
    },
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "566786",
        "detail": {
            "lastUpdate": "2015-01-22T22:06:22.951Z",
            "registrationDate": "2015-01-22T02:15:07.379Z",
            "firstName": "Testing",
            "lastName": "Testing",
        },
        "info": {
            "email": "testing@abcdefgxxxxxx.com",
        }
    },
}
```

How should I filter out those fields that I don't want?

Comment: If you're retrieving this data from a `mongodb` instance using `mongoose`, you can filter that fields with the `select` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the properties by deleting them

```
delete user.user.info.password;
delete user.user.info.confirmationToken;

return res.send({"user": user});
```